# How can I delete a React Class Component from its Parent Class OnClick of Delete button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a project that I'm using PHP and React on it, it consists on making a CRUD system with AJAX Calls.

[This is the interface I made so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1PRp.jpg)

The problem is that when I click delete, the request is sent and the data row is deleted, but when the parent refreshes it doesn't remove the deleted item from the list.

This is the User class component (for each row):

```
    class User extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isEditing: false,

            id: this.props.id,
            username: this.props.username,
            email: this.props.email,
            password: this.props.password,

            refID: '',
            refUsername: '',
            refEmail: '',
            refPassword: ''   
        };

        this.refID = this.props.id;
        this.refUsername = this.props.username;
        this.refEmail = this.props.email;
        this.refPassword = this.props.password;

        this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);
    }


    handleEdit() {
        this.setState({isEditing: true});
    }


    handleDelete() {
        $.ajax({  
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost/CRUD/server/api/delete.php',
            data: {
                id: this.state.id
            },
            success: function(response) {
                toast.success('User deleted successfully!', {
                    position: "bottom-left",
                    autoClose: 3000,
                    hideProgressBar: true,
                    closeOnClick: true,
                    pauseOnHover: true,
                    draggable: true,
                    progress: undefined,
                    icon: CheckCircleIcon
                });
                console.log(response);

                // Remove the user from the list.
                
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                toast.error('Error deleting user!', {
                    position: "bottom-left",
                    autoClose: 3000,
                    hideProgressBar: true,
                    closeOnClick: true,
                    pauseOnHover: true,
                    draggable: true,
                    progress: undefined,
                    icon: CheckCircleIcon
                });
                console.log(' response: ', jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)

                return false;
            }
        })

        this.props.rerender();
    }

    handleCancel() {
        this.setState({
            isEditing: false
        });
    }

    handleSave() {
        $.ajax({  
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost/CRUD/server/api/update.php', 
            data: {
                id: this.refID,
                username: this.refUsername,
                email: this.refEmail,
                password: this.refPassword
            },
            success: function() {
                toast.success("Successfully updated the user information.",{
                    position: "bottom-left",
                    autoClose: 3000,
                    hideProgressBar: true,
                    closeOnClick: true,
                    pauseOnHover: true,
                    draggable: true,
                    progress: undefined,
                    icon: CheckCircleIcon
                    });
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                toast.error("Error updating the user information.");
                console.log(' response: ', jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            }
        })
        // Update the state with the new values. As well as changing the display back to the original.
        this.setState({isEditing: false, id: this.refID, username: this.refUsername, email: this.refEmail, password: this.refPassword});
    }



    
    render() {
        let DisplayMode, EditMode;

        

        DisplayMode = (
            <div className="Row">
                <div className="Cell C1" id='DataID'>
                    <p>{this.state.id}</p>
                </div>
                <div className="Cell C2" id='DataUsername'>
                    <p>{this.state.username}</p>
                </div>
                <div className="Cell C3" id='DataEmail'>
                    <p>{this.state.email}</p>
                </div>
                <div className="Cell C4" id='DataPassword'>
                    <p>{this.state.password}</p>
                </div>
                <div className="Cell C5" id='DataActions'>
                    <div className="Button Secondary Edit">
                        {/* On click of the Edit button, switch the cells with inputs, and change the buttons to save button*/}
                        <EditIcon onClick={() => this.handleEdit()} />
                    </div>
    
                    <div className="Button Primary Delete">
                        <DeleteIcon onClick={() => this.handleDelete()} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );

        EditMode = (
            <div className="Row EditMode">

                <div className="Cell C1" id="DataID">
                    <p>{this.props.id}</p>
                </div>

                <div className="Cell C2 Editing" id="DataUsername">
                    <input type='text' placeholder='Edit username' defaultValue={this.state.username} onChange={e => {this.refUsername = e.target.value}}/>
                </div>

                <div className="Cell C3 Editing" id="DataEmail">
                    <input type='text' placeholder='Edit e-mail' defaultValue={this.state.email} onChange={e => {this.refEmail = e.target.value}}/>
                </div>

                <div className="Cell C4 Editing" id="DataPassword">
                    <input type='text' placeholder='Edit password' defaultValue={this.state.password} onChange={e => {this.refPassword = e.target.value}}/>
                </div>

                <div className="Cell C5" id="DataActions">
                    <div className="Button Secondary Edit">
                        <CancelIcon onClick={() => this.handleCancel()}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="Button Primary Delete">
                        <SaveIcon onClick= {() => this.handleSave()} />
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        );
        
        const CurrentMode = () => { 
            return(
                this.state.isEditing ? EditMode : DisplayMode
            )
         };

        return (
            <>
                <CurrentMode/>
            </>
        );
    };
};
```

And this is the code of the Parent class (For the entire table):

```
class UsersListView extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoaded: false,
            error: null,
            users: [],
            counter: 0,
            isLoading: false
        };

        this.handleRefresh = this.handleRefresh.bind(this);
        
    };

    rerender = () => {
        this.forceUpdate();
    };
    forceUpdate = () => {
        this.setState((state) => ({
            counter: state.counter + 1,
            isLoaded: false
        }));
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.handleRefresh();
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        console.log("Updated");
        () => {
            this.handleRefresh();
        }, [this.state.users]
    };


    handleRefresh() {
        fetch("http://localhost/CRUD/server/api/read.php")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((result) => {
            this.setState({
                isLoading: false,
                isLoaded: true,
                users: result
            });
        },
        (error) => {
            this.setState({
                isLoading: false,
                isLoaded: false,
                error
            });
            console.log(error)
        }
        )

        this.forceUpdate();
    }



    
    render() {

        return this.state.isLoaded ?
                // If the data is loaded, render the users.        
                
                    this.state.users.map((user) => {
                        return (
                            <User 
                                rerender={this.rerender} 
                                key={user.id} 
                                id={user.id} 
                                username={user.username} 
                                email={user.email} 
                                password={user.password}
                            />
                        )
                    }) 
                // If the data is not loaded, display a loading message.
                : (

                <div className='User-Loading'>
                   <div className='Loading'>
                        <div className="loader">
                            <span></span>
                            <span></span>
                            <span></span>
                            <span></span>
                            <span></span>
                            <span></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className='User-Loading-Text'>
                        <h3>Loading...</h3>

                        <p>Taking too long? Check the API link if is connected.</p>

                        <div className='button' onClick={this.handleRefresh}>
                            <RefreshIcon/>
                            Retry
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                )
    }
}

export default UsersListView;
```

### Heading ##UPDATES:

I brought the `handleDelete()` function to the parent class, and I called it using the props of the child component, and it worked.

I also updated the state of the parent to solve the main issue of removing the row after each delete.

Comment: This problem is in the backend, not front. It can mean that your item is not properly removed from your db

Comment: I kept checking on the database and tried adding a refresh button that re-renders the component, and the fetch function removes the deleted row successfully, the only issue is that I don't want to click the button each time to refresh, I need it to remove the row instantly after that the AJAX call happens.

Comment: You are missing the update of the users in the state after a successful delete

Comment: I suggest to move the handleDelete func to the parent component and pass it as a prop to the child, and don't forget to update the users in the state after successful delete, tip: you can simply call handleRefresh method

Comment: Thank you! I solved it by using your method.